# Retorno função boolean via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho a seguinte chamada ajax na minha página:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento',
    data: { contratocod: contratocod, numeroserie: numerodeserie },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(retorno) {
        alert('success:' + retorno);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

E o seguinte método na minha controller que chama outro método da model que retorna um bool:

```
public JsonResult EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento(string contratocod, string numeroserie)
{
    ControleFuncionamentoModel cfm = new ControleFuncionamentoModel();
    return Json(cfm.EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento(contratocod, numeroserie));
}
```

Coloquei um breakpoint no método da controller, porém não está parando. 
Quero retornar o boolean do método EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento via ajax. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Abra o console do browser (F12) e veja se está ocorrendo algum erro na chamada Ajax. Abra também o link no navegador, e veja se o controller está funcionando da forma esperada.

Comment: Sem erro na chamada do Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido. 
O método da controller ficou do mesmo jeito:

```
public JsonResult EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento(string contratocod, string numeroserie)
{
    ControleFuncionamentoModel cfm = new ControleFuncionamentoModel();
    return Json(cfm.EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento(contratocod, numeroserie));
}
```

A chamada ajax, troquei a chamada da url, chamando agora via @Url.Action:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento")',
     data: { contratocod: contratocod, numeroserie: numerodeserie },
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     success: function(retorno) {
            alert('success:' + retorno);
     },
     error: function(retorno) {
            alert('error: '+ retorno);
     }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

O problema está na sua URL, essa URL não seria valida em nenhum cenário que consigo imagina, você deve colocar a URL de acesso a essa ACTION no controller.

Segue um exemplo de ajax com MVC

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zXCm87

Exemplo:

```
public class Home: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento(string contratocod, string numeroserie)
    {
        ControleFuncionamentoModel cfm = new ControleFuncionamentoModel();
        return Json(cfm.EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento(contratocod, numeroserie));
    }
}
```

Já o Ajax séria assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento")',
    data: { contratocod: contratocod, numeroserie: numerodeserie },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(retorno) {
        alert('success:' + retorno);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

ou assim (caso a chama esteja dentro de uma arquivo Razor):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EquipamentoTemControleFuncionamento", "Home")',
    data: { contratocod: contratocod, numeroserie: numerodeserie },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(retorno) {
        alert('success:' + retorno);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: não funcionou desse jeito

Comment: Qual o erro gerado pelo AJAX?